# Applying PDF format to excel on Java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am building an application which applies the formatting available in a pdf (spaces and styles), to an excel file. Is there a library that could help me with this?

Comment: Did you look at https://poi.apache.org/?

Comment: Thank you sir but I have a problem on the format of the excel not getting it right, in the excel the data comes one below the other rather than the actual format. Any suggestion?